# Custom error message validation pop up not getting closed on single click in identity user abp framework

Tags: c#, .net, abp

I have added couple of custom controls in Identity user form using abp framework. I have added a check box and a dropdown.

On click of the check box I need to do some validations.

I have added custom controls using ConfigureExtraProperties in ModuleExtensionConfigurator.cs file.

The popup error message is not getting closed on single click. I have to click close two times to close the popup window.

```
user.AddOrUpdateProperty(
UserConsts.DefaultMaintenancePropertyName,
options =>
{
options.Validators.Add(context =>
{
var DefaultManint = blnDefaultMaint;

                      if (blnDefaultMaint == true )
                      {
                          context.ValidationErrors.Add(
                              new ValidationResult(
                                  strDefaulMaintUser + " is the current default maintenance contact.There Can Only be One default maintenance contact per Property.",
                                  new[] { UserConsts.DefaultMaintenancePropertyName }
                              )
                          );
                      }
                  });                     
              });
```